# “To seek without... getting off a shot”

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

A puzzling sentence from the Preacher graphic novel, book 3:

> [...] He’d taken the band of Kiowa he’d sought without them getting off a shot”

[image]

What would mean:

1. “To **take** the band of Kiowa” - kill them?
2. “To seek without them” - ?
3. “To get off a shot” - to be shot?

Comment: You misquote the graphic with "without them getting off the shot". It is "without them getting off ***a*** shot". It means the Kiowa were captured or killed before they (Kiowa) could fire any gun, although plainly the reverse was not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **take** in this context means "to best", or "win a competition against".  "I could take him" = "I could beat him".  In this case victory was won by killing, but not always.

2) **he'd sought** = "he'd looked for".  The next section is "without them getting off a shot".  The **without them** is not part of the **looking for**.

3) **without them getting off a shot**  means "unable to fire their weapons"